# Python - classmethod in base class accessible via child class, without passing in class

Tags: python, static-methods, class-method, first-class

I'm trying to define some methods in a base class that can then be used as class/static methods on a child class, like so:

```
class Common():
    @classmethod
    def find(cls, id): # When Foo.find is called, cls needs to be Foo
        rows = Session.query(cls)
        rows = rows.filter(cls.id == id)
        return rows.first()

class Foo(Common):
    pass

>> Foo.find(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: find() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How can I define `find` in `Common` such that it is usable in `Foo` without having to redefine it in `Foo` or do a passthrough in `Foo` to the method in `Common`?  I also don't want to have to call `Foo.find(Foo, 3)`.  I'm using Python 2.6.

**Edit:** derp, looks like I had another `find` declared in `Common` that I hadn't noticed, and it was causing the `TypeError`.  I would delete this question, but Nix mentioned code smells, so now I ask for suggestions on how to avoid defining `find` across all my model classes in a non-smelly way.

Comment: This smells, can I ask why you want the class?

Comment: I'm using SQLAlchemy and would like `find`, `exists`, etc. methods accessible in all my models, like I'm used to with Ruby on Rails.  Since I'm going to be doing the same thing in each, I didn't want to define them in all the models with only the model changing each time.

Comment: According to the documentation, http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.7/library/functions.html#classmethod, "If a class method is called for a derived class, the derived class object is passed as the implied first argument." So... according to the documentation, your example should work as shown. And testing it out myself (with a slight alteration to the body of `Common.find`, but no changes to the signature of the function itself), it works just fine.

Comment: Are you using the declarative form of SQLAlchemy or the traditional pattern?

Comment: "looks like I had another find declared in Common that I hadn't noticed, and it was causing the TypeError." Heh, and I was even thinking of suggesting that you might have had a different `find` declared somewhere else in `Common` somehow, but decided not to for some reason.

Comment: JAB: yep, my example works--there was another instance of `find` declared in `Common` later on, which was messing things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had another `find` method defined in `Common`, so that was the one getting used and causing the `TypeError`.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't quite answer your question but it might be of use to you.

An SQLAlchemy session instance has [`query_property()`](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/session.html?highlight=query_property#session-utilites) which returns a class property that produces a query against the class. So you could implement something similar to your `find()` method thus:

```
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

class Foo(Base):
    pass

Foo.query.get(id)
```